# Insert text file data into sql database

Tags: asp.net

How to insert or export txt file's comma seperated data into sql database using c#. Values available in the text file should be inserted in the specific columns of the sql table

Comment: did you try anything? show it?

Comment: Its in the office system and it ws nt working

Comment: @Bhawani, [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for learn how you can improve your question.

Comment: Here is my code how i tried to perform the same.